# How to solve TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, regex

I have typo errors in my data. In particular, I need to convert pandas DataFrame's column values from string to float. However, a simple `float(value)` fails throwing this error:

```
"could not convert string to float: '33q.200088'"
```

Therefore I apply regex to remove all non-digits:

```
re.sub(r"\D", "", num)
```

However, then I get the error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` for the following case:

```
num = -97.94111109999999
```

Important: I want to maintain the `-` sign.

Comment: So you're looking to remove letters?

Comment: @C.Nivs: Yes. And deal with negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This code should make it work:

```
float(re.sub('[a-z]', "", str(num)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`num` is a signed `float` type, not a `string` or `bytes`

`re.sub("[a-zA-Z]", "", str(num))`

That will return a stringType that keeps the `-` and the `.`

You should be able to convert that to `float`